# Зависает покадровая анимация Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Пытаюсь делать кликер. Сделал покадровую анимацию для модельки персонажа.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.homelessAnimation:
            animationDrawable.start();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animationDrawable.stop();
                }
            }, 320);
```

При многократном нажатии анимация зависает, приходится кликать повторно, чтобы отвисла. Подскажите, либо намекните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, это происходит из-за большого кол-ва кадров, их получилось 17. Минимизировал, больше не зависает. Вопрос не актуален.